# Is there some wrapper for running GUI applications under a fake screen resolution?

Tags: gui, window-manager

Some applications behave differently at a different screen resolution. Is there any way to get the system to report a different, user-specified, resolution to a GUI application when starting it?

By *behave differently* I mean for example their unresizable window is smaller (not necessarily physically, for obvious reasons, but fewer pixels) if I first switched the monitor to a lower resolution.

Something like:

```
~$ sudolution 800x600 unresizableapp
```

Or is there any method to **force**-resize unresizable windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt a fake resolution can be provided somehow. The resolution can be received from X extension `RANDR`, e.g. with the tool `xrandr`.

What you can do instead:

- For resolutions smaller than current screen:

Use a nested X server like Xephyr with a custom resolution:

```
Xephyr :5 -retro -screen 400x300x24
```

Run desired application with `DISPLAY=:5 application`. It makes sense to run a window manager on `:5`, too. (`400x300` is the resolution, `x24` is color depth.)

- For resolution bigger than current screen:

Change current screen to have a virtual bigger display:

```
xrandr --output VGA-1 --panning 3000x2000
```

Replace example `VGA-1` with an output name given in output of `xrandr`. To turn panning of, run with `--panning 0x0`.

Comment: `Xvfb` is another option but only if you don't need to see what's happening or are prepared to use something like VNC to look in.

Comment: Are there ways in which using a nested X server is better than using VNC?

Comment: @argle Xephyr is immediatly visible and fast. VNC needs a server and a viewer, needs more resources and is slow.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the *size* in pixels of a screen, and the *resolution* in pixels per inch. Your pseudo solution seems to want to change the size, not the resolution.

You can use `xrandr` to change the reported resolution of the screen with option `--dpi`.

Comment: Some applications are programmed to take up "as much of the screen as possible anyway". A resolution-oriented solution, as opposed to a DPI-oriented solution, is the only way.